# What is the finite character of an endomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I read an exercise where the term "finite character" was used with "endomorphisms". It was link with the iterative sequences $K_k=Ker(f^k)$ and $J_k=Im(f^k)$. There exists a minimum index $r$ such that : $K_r = K_{r+1}$ and $J_r = J_{r+1}$.

So if someone knows what this term really mean it could be nice to share. Or maybe some references about it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us more about the exercise or where exactly you encountered this exercise.

Comment: My best guess is that the exercise is referring to the [character of a representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(mathematics)#Character_of_a_representation)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry I've edited the post.